# Passport deserialize function is removing user from the session

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies, passport.js

To be frank, I just started learning passport today.  I feel I understand some of how passport is working, but I'm still trying to familiarize myself.  My problem here (I think) is that my user is getting removed from the session, which is preventing me from reaching my authenticated routes.  I console.logged the user id in the deserialize function to check if it was getting stored in the session, and it is ...

```
  //serialize user into the session
passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
   done(null,user.id); 
});

//deserialize the user from the session
passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){

    console.log('user id is: ' + id); //works and logs user id

    User.findById(id, function(err,user){
       done(err,user); 
    });
});
```

Here are my routes and passport middleware ...

```
app.post('/login', function(req,res,next){
    passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err,user,info){
       if(err){
           console.log("we have an internal error!");
           return next(err);
       }
       if(!user){
           return res.send({success:false, message:'failed to login!'});
       }else{
           req.login(user, function(err){
                if(err){
                    return next(err);
                }
                    return res.send({ success : true, message : 'authentication succeeded' }); 
            });
       }

    })(req,res,next);
}); 

//route middleware to make sure that a user is logged in 

    function isLoggedIn(req,res,next){

     //if the user is authenticated in the session, carry on
         if(req.isAuthenticated()){
               next();
         }

    //if they are not authenticated in the session, redirect them to the home page
         res.redirect('/');
    }
```

Any help, insights, advice is greatly appreciated; thanks!

Comment: I think your problem is that you need to use `return` in `isLoggedIn` if  `req.isAuthenticated()`. Right now you do `next()` and then make `res.redirect('/');`. And without checking the db and knowing **for sure** that the session is gone - don't make such an assumptions :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm just trying to come up with an idea on what might be wrong .. been at this for a while now :/  .  You said put a return in the isLogged() function, but don't I need next() to escape middleware limbo?

Comment: Yeah, but calling `next` doesn't stop the function executing further on. So you are now calling **both** `next` AND `res.redirect`. Put return after calling next :) Like `next(); return;` or even `return next();`

Comment: I really appreciate it Andrey, that was the solution :) .  Everything is finally working!  I always thought that next() acted as a return too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're always redirecting the user to the index page in your `isLoggedIn` middleware. Need to use return:

```
function isLoggedIn(req,res,next){
     if(req.isAuthenticated()){
           next();
           // STOPS further execution of this function and prevents redirecting the user
           return;
     }
     res.redirect('/');
}
```

Keep in mind that it's just JavaScript - no framework does any changes - Express, Passport, even Promises are pure JS and they don't modify the way the virtual machine works. GL!

p.s.
If things go wrong, especially in the beginning, I recommend using `if-else` statement. You wouldn't have problems this way:

```
if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
} else {
    res.redirect('/');
}
```